# closure requires unique access

Tags: closures, rust

I'm trying to avoid repeating myself by using a closure in the following code:

```rust
fn add_raw(&mut self, pair: RawLinkPair) {
    let convert = |raw: &RawLink| {
        Link{
            id:         self.get_or_create(raw.name).id,
            flow:       raw.flow,
        }
    };

    println!("Hive received pair: {}", pair);
    let parent = convert(&pair.parent);
    let child = convert(&pair.child);
    self.link_concepts(parent, child);
}
```

That doesn't work. It gives me this error:

```
hive.rs:64:9: 64:13 error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because previous closure requires unique access
hive.rs:64         self.link_concepts(parent, child);
                   ^~~~
hive.rs:55:23: 60:10 note: previous borrow of `self` occurs here due to use in closure; the unique capture prevents subsequent moves or borrows of `self` until the borrow ends
hive.rs:55         let convert = |raw: RawLink| {
hive.rs:56             Link{
hive.rs:57                 id:         self.get_or_create(raw.name).id,
hive.rs:58                 flow:       raw.flow,
hive.rs:59             }
hive.rs:60         };
hive.rs:65:6: 65:6 note: previous borrow ends here
hive.rs:54     fn add_raw(&mut self, pair: RawLinkPair) {
...
hive.rs:65     }
               ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

In this case I'm not actually saving myself too many keystrokes. I can type everything out by hand and it works fine:

```rust
fn add_raw(&mut self, pair: RawLinkPair) {
    let parent = Link {
        id:     self.get_or_create(pair.parent.name).id,
        flow:   pair.parent.flow,
    };

    let child = Link {
        id:     self.get_or_create(pair.child.name).id,
        flow:   pair.child.flow,
    };

    self.link_concepts(parent, child);
}
```

I understand the error (so I think), but:

1. Is there something wrong with using a closure here in principal or did I just write this wrong?
2. Is there a more idiomatic way to write this, or at least, how do I satisfy the borrow checker?
3. This might be a dim question, but why doesn't the borrow just end immediately after the last time `convert` is called? It seems strange to me especially when I compare it to the bottom version, which ultimately does the same steps minus the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to fix it like this (something you called "satisfy the borrow checker"):

```
fn add_raw(&mut self, pair: RawLinkPair) {
    let (parent, child) = {
        let convert = |raw: RawLink| {
            Link{
                id:         self.get_or_create(raw.name).id,
                flow:       raw.flow,
            }
        };

        (convert(pair.parent.clone()), convert(pair.child.clone()))
    };
    self.link_concepts(parent, child);
}
```

As far as I know, this is something inexpressible in current Rust directly (i.e. without closures). Closures take their environment through `&only` reference (currently it is only available to compiler), which forbids taking other references until it goes out of scope. It is like `&mut` reference but not necessarily tied to mutability. Closure environment capture happens upon its creation, so lifetime of this capture extends to the end of the function, hence you're getting the error.

Why closures should take their environment by unique reference I don't know, though.

Comment: The problem here is just that closures do borrow their environment (not due to any form of uniqueness in that borrow); the closure's borrow conflicts with the mutable/unique borrow of `self` for `self.link_concepts`. I.e. it's the `link_concepts` call that is upsetting things. One would see identical behaviour (for the same reason) with just `let x = &self; self.link_concepts(...);` (i.e. no closure). (Thinking about `&only` + closures is entirely a red herring.)

Comment: That said, if `.link_concepts` was a `&self` method, then it would be relevant that the closure is forced to take a non-aliasable (aka unique) borrow to be able to call the `&mut self` `.get_or_create` method (the non-aliased borrow is required to guarantee that the `&mut self` used in that method is also non-aliased).

Comment: @dbaupp, thanks for the explanation. I guess I was confused by pcwalton's remark in that thread on Reddit about several kinds of references in closures, and "unique capture" part in the error message.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the "unique capture" part of the error message does obscure the reason for this exact problem.