# How to refactor out repeated manipulations of local mutable variables?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have code like this.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 123;
    let mut y = 456;
    let mut z = 789;

    x += y; y *= z; z %= x; // random operations
    x = 1;
    x += y; y *= z; z %= x;
    z = z & y;
    x += y; y *= z; z %= x;
    println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
}
```

Quite contrived, but hopefully the idea is clear --- I have these local variables that I manipulate in a certain complex way more than once.

Obviously I'd like to avoid the duplication and refactor out that manipulation. At the same time, there are so many variables involved that I'd prefer not to pass all of them as mutable reference arguments to an outside utility function.

If this were, say, C++, I might stash the variables in a global scope and define another function, or in more recent versions, use a capturing lambda. I tried to do the corresponding thing in Rust with a closure:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 123;
    let mut y = 456;
    let mut z = 789;

    let f = || {
        x += y; y *= z; z %= x; // random operations
    };

    f();
    x = 1;
    f();
    z = z & y;
    f();
    println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
}
```

But this doesn't compile, because Rust tells me I borrowed `x, y, z` to `f`. It seems the very existence of `f` means I can't use `x, y, z` in `main` anymore. This Rust error would make sense if I were trying to pass `f` out of the function or spawn a process with it or something, but I'm not, and it's evidently safe if I "manually inline" the function as in the first version.

Is there a neat Rust way to do this?

By the way, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624381/closure-requires-unique-access) and I see that I can avoid an error in the last `println!` by declaring `f` inside a block that terminates before that statement, but that doesn't help me if I want to mutate the variables in between calls to `f`.

Comment: I also was expecting closures to work this way, and am a bit disappointed by the solutions posted so far; it's a shame to have to use something feature gated... or to have to add something to the parent namespace, potentially far from the call sites for f.

Comment: Some stuff from one of Jonathan Blow's recent videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Nc68IdNKdg is really ringing true for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simpler ways of doing this is with a macro:

```
macro_rules! f {
    ($x:ident, $y:ident, $z:ident) => {{
        $x += $y;
        $y *= $z;
        $z %= $x;
    }}
}
```

This can be invoked with `f!(x, y, z)`. It’s not much nicer than writing a function which takes three `&mut int` arguments, however.

Now in this *specific* case, because `x`, `y` and `z` are in scope, provided you write the macro after them you can use `x`, `y` and `z` without needing to pass them through the macro call (recall that Rust’s are hygienic macros). That is, you can write

```
macro_rules! f {
    () => {{
        x += y;
        y *= z;
        z %= x;
    }}
}
```

Here’s the code in full:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

fn main() {
    let mut x = 123i;
    let mut y = 456i;
    let mut z = 789i;

    macro_rules! f {
        () => {{
            x += y;
            y *= z;
            z %= x;
        }}
    }

    f!()
    x = 1;
    f!()
    z = z & y;
    f!()
    println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
}
```

In the playpen: http://is.gd/sCaYMS

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a Cell. The contents of a Cell are mutable regardless of the Cell's mutability. It will make the code uglier but at least it compiles. Performance shouldn't be affected as far as I know.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let x = Cell::new(123i);
    let y = Cell::new(456i);
    let z = Cell::new(789i);

    let f = || {
        x.set(x.get() + y.get());
        y.set(y.get() * z.get());
        z.set(z.get() % x.get());
    };

    f();
    x.set(1);
    f();
    z.set(z.get() & x.get());
    f();
    println!("{} {} {}", x, y, z);
}
```

Probably a better solution is to abstract the data and the functions operating on them as struct.

```
#[deriving(Show)]
struct Data {
    x: int,
    y: int,
    z: int
}

impl Data {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        self.x += self.y; 
        self.y *= self.z;
        self.z %= self.x;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut data = Data { x: 123, y: 456, z: 789 };

    data.f();
    data.x = 1;
    data.f();
    data.z = data.z & data.x;
    data.f();
    println!("{}", data);
}
```

Comment: I hope (fingers crossed) that by 1.0 either rust closures or macros will provide a cleaner solution, but they are both expected to see breaking changes before 1.0.  I upvoted this answer since these solutions are most likely to keep working for a while.